# How using inline if statement inside bracket

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want using inline if statement in angular2 template like this?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="value" class="form-control" (blur)="onBlur()">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name?item.name:item}}</option>
</select>
```

how to make `{{item.name?item.name:item}}` posible using inline if statement?

Comment: Did you tried `[ngValue]="item.value ? item.value : item"`

Comment: You can use it like you are using it :) It should  work, what is the problem?

Comment: my problem is same time item is string and others is object.
so i want to make this dynamic

Comment: If `item` is a string what do you expect from `item.name`? A string does not contain key-value pairs. If it was an object that will be true. Here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/0HZ1VQgudgk5ZHRTVpn7?p=preview

Comment: Do you mean `items` contain both strings and objects? If that is the problem, you should check the type of the `item`.

Comment: i have tried `{{item.name?item.name:item}}` but i get disply object object

Comment: I updated the plunker, it should work even in that case http://plnkr.co/edit/0HZ1VQgudgk5ZHRTVpn7?p=preview

Comment: Can you share your  `items` array so we can see the problem more clearly?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First convert item name to boolean by `!!` below should work

```
{{!!item.name ? item.name : item}}
```

Comment: what does it change?

Comment: No need for this.

Comment: A conditional statement should be checked by a boolean value for best practice

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül what do you mean by no need?  The OP had the code without the !! and it was not working for them, no?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake it works without `!!`, @Steffi is right.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ternary operator (that's what you already use) or use `<template>` tag ([see more](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template)):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="value" class="form-control" (blur)="onBlur()">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">
    <template [ngIf]="item.name">{{ item.name }}</template>
    <template [ngIf]="!item.name">{{ item }}</template>
  </option>
</select>
```

Of course you can use `ngSwitch` instead of `*ngIf`, but it does not change a lot.

The advantage of using `<template>` tag is that it does not create a real HTML tag which is not allowed inside of option.